# Sort by date in descending order in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I would like to sort my list in a descending order by date which as a "New user list", in the database I have a column which is

```
t.datetime "created_at",                                      null: false
```

This is the time when a new user registered, in the view, I have the code like this:

```
%table.table.table-striped.table-hover
      %thead
      %h3 New Users
      %hr
        %th Name
        %th Company
        %th Role
        %th Created date
        %th{:width => '50'}
        %th{:width => '50'}
        %th{:width => '50'}
      %tbody
      - @users.each do |user|
        -if user.role == "trial-member"
          - @created_at.sort{|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at}.each do |created_at|
            %tr
            %td
              = user.first_name
              = user.last_name
            %td= user.company
            %td= user.role
            %td= user.created_at
            %td= link_to 'Approve', edit_user_path(user),  {:class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm'}
```

but this gives an error that "undefined method `sort' for nil:NilClass", what shall I do to sort the list in table descending by created date? Thank you.

Comment: For those that downvoted this question, please provide actionable feedback to the person asking the question so they can improve it. Lets help make our community more awesome!

Answer (score 25):

In your controller:

```
@users = User.order('created_at DESC')
```

Just add: `order('created_at DESC')` in your logic where you're fetching `@users`.

In your view, you can now get rid off of `- @created_at.sort{|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at}.each`:

```
%h3 New Users
%table.table.table-striped.table-hover
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th Company
      %th Role
      %th Created date
      %th{:width => '50'}
      %th{:width => '50'}
      %th{:width => '50'}
  %tbody
    - @users.each do |user|
      -if user.role == "trial-member"
        %tr
          %td
            = user.first_name
            = user.last_name
          %td= user.company
          %td= user.role
          %td= user.created_at
          %td= link_to 'Approve', edit_user_path(user),  {:class => 'btn btn-success btn-sm'}
```

Error you are seeing is because `@created_at` is not an enumerable object, hence it does not respond to `sort`.

Comment: You can also use `User.order(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 1):

It's because `@created_at` is not defined anywhere. So, any instance variable which is not defined, by default returns nil. If you want to display the users in sorted order, then you need to fetch `@users` in order.

```
@users = User.order(created_at: :desc)
```